# From wordpress to SPA application - SEO issues

Tags: wordpress, seo, single-page-application

I need to test in terms of SEO a new page which was exported from wordpress to single page application. I want to keep my rank in search results. Unfortunately I am not sure how to do it properly.

Could you please give me any advice?

I know that I need to verify sitemap and broken links. Could you please recommend any tools to do it automatically?

Comment: Primarily single page website is not good for SEO.

Answer (score -1):

The most important thing to do is to use the same URLs you have from your old website, or use 301 redirect method to redirect the old URLs to the new one.

Regarding the one pages, its not good for SEO since all your content will be in the same page, and here you can't target many keywords.

Still you can use one page website with advanced techniques to rank one many keywords but here it will affect the UX.

Regarding the XML site, since you have one page in your new website, you have to redirect all the pages to the new one using 301 redirect or you will have many 404s in the webmaster tool.